# Linux Mint not shutting down

Tags: linux-mint, shutdown, kernel-panic

people!

I use Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia and it's not shutting down sometimes. I have been researching and looks like a kernel panic with a BAD RIP value code,but I'm not sure and I don't know how to solve it.

Sorry for the lack of information, but I don't know too much about Linux, but if some more information were necessary I can provide it. It's happening almost everyday

I'm attaching the image of a screen that appear when it's not turning off and I press ESC:
[image: Screen]

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is this the result of choosing shutdown from the Mint menu? How often is sometimes?

Comment: This could be a kernel bug (try the latest kernel 5.12.13) or a HW bug - in which case I've no idea - they are a billion of options.

Comment: Jeremy, I type poweroff on terminal to turn off the notebook. It started to happens in the begginer of this month, it was 1 or 2 times in a week. But this week was 3rd day in a row that it happened

Comment: Artem, I will try upgrade kernel to check if it works! My notebook is a Dell Inspiron 15 Serie 3000, it looks like working fine. I already had a problem with this notebook using Ubuntu, the touchpad wasnt working. But when I sent to a professional, he said me the hw was ok, the problem was the Ubuntu kernel was not recognizing the touchpad and recommended to downgrade the kernel and that worked. I'm using Linux Mint for almost a year and it was working fine until now. How can I know if it is the hardware?

Comment: If Windows works, it must be a bug in Linux.

Comment: So I decided to install the Linux Mint 20.1 and it looks like working fine now! Thanks everyone!